# Need multiple copies of one resultset in sql without using loop

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Following is the sample data. I need to make 3 copies of this data in t sql without using loop and return as one resultset. This is sample data not real.

```
42  South Yorkshire
43  Lancashire
44  Norfolk
```

Edit: I need multiple copies and I have no idea in advance that how many copies I need I have to decide this on the basis of dates. Date might be 1st jan to 3rd Jan OR 1st jan to 8th Jan.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know about *better*  but this is definatley more creative! you can use a [CROSS JOIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690.aspx).
**EDIT:** put some code in to generate a date range, you can change the date range, the rows in the #date are your multiplier.

```
  declare @startdate datetime
, @enddate datetime
create table #data1 ([id] int , [name] nvarchar(100))
create table #dates ([date] datetime)


INSERT #data1 SELECT 42,  'South Yorkshire'
INSERT #data1 SELECT 43,  'Lancashire'
INSERT #data1 SELECT 44,  'Norfolk'


set @startdate = '1Jan2010'
set @enddate = '3Jan2010'

WHILE (@startdate <= @enddate)
BEGIN   
INSERT #dates SELECT @startdate
set @startdate=@startdate+1
END


SELECT [id] , [name] from #data1 cross join #dates

drop table #data1
drop table #dates
```

Comment: I like it, it means that the main table only gets scanned once.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

**You could always use a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to do the dirty work**

Replace the `WHERE Counter < 4` with the amount of duplicates you need.

```
CREATE TABLE City (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(32))

INSERT INTO City VALUES (42, 'South Yorkshire')
INSERT INTO City VALUES (43, 'Lancashire')
INSERT INTO City VALUES (44, 'Norfolk')

/*
  The CTE duplicates every row from CTE for the amount
  specified by Counter
*/
;WITH CityCTE (ID, Name, Counter) AS 
(
  SELECT  c.ID, c.Name, 0 AS Counter
  FROM    City c
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT  c.ID, c.Name, Counter + 1
  FROM    City c  
          INNER JOIN CityCTE cte ON cte.ID = c.ID
  WHERE   Counter < 4
)
SELECT  ID, Name
FROM    CityCTE
ORDER BY 1, 2

DROP TABLE City
```

Comment: Thanks, and Good, it is a little hard for me but I will certainly try to get understanding of common table expression.

Comment: Can you please also help me on this too.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227808/get-top-one-record-of-same-fk-on-date-difference

Comment: @Muhammad Kashif Nadeem - I've posted a first try. Could you verify it?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most efficient way of doing it, but it should work.

```
(select ....)
union all
(select ....)
union all
(select ....)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume the table is named CountyPopulation:

```
SELECT * FROM CountyPopulation
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM CountyPopulation
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM CountyPopulation
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a cursor. The set-based approach would be to use a Calendar table. So first we make our calendar table which need only be done once and be somewhat permanent:

```
Create Table dbo.Calendar ( Date datetime not null Primary Key Clustered )
GO
; With Numbers As
(
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY S1.object_id ) As [Counter]
From sys.columns As s1
 Cross Join sys.columns As s2
)
Insert dbo.Calendar([Date])
Select DateAdd(d, [Counter], '19000101')
From Numbers
Where [Counter] <= 100000
GO
```

I populated it with a 100K dates which goes into 2300. Obviously you can always expand it. Next we generate our test data:

```
Create Table dbo.Data(Id int not null, [Name] nvarchar(20) not null)
GO
Insert dbo.Data(Id, [Name]) Values(42,'South Yorkshire')
Insert dbo.Data(Id, [Name]) Values(43, 'Lancashire')
Insert dbo.Data(Id, [Name]) Values(44, 'Norfolk')
GO
```

Now the problem becomes trivial:

```
Declare @Start datetime
Declare @End datetime
Set @Start = '2010-01-01'
Set @End = '2010-01-03'
Select Dates.[Date], Id, [Name]
From dbo.Data
 Cross Join (
              Select [Date]
              From dbo.Calendar
              Where [Date] >= @Start
              And [Date] <= @End
             ) As Dates
```

Answer (score 0):

By far the best solution is CROSS JOIN. Most natural.

See my answer here: [How to retrieve rows multiple times in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209395/how-to-retrieve-rows-multiple-times-in-sql-server/1209421#1209421)

If you have a Numbers table lying around, it's even easier. You can DATEDIFF the dates to give you the filter on the Numbers table

Comment: Thanks for the link of other question.